# Communication Between Pods in Different Cluster in K8s using yaml

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

Can some one provide References/Basic Idea how communication is done between pods in different clusters.
Suppose Cluster A has Pod A and Cluster B has Pod B. So how we can ensure Pod A can communicate with Pod B using yaml? -Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the pods are in different clusters, they can't directly communicate with each other (without using NodePort or LoadBalancer services, or otherwise making the destination service accessible from outside its own cluster).

Comment: okay can u elaborate a little. though we are creating load balancer. we can access service but  how actually pod communicate @DavidMaze

Comment: You'd make a call to the load balancer endpoint, the same way as any other process not inside Cluster B would invoke Pod B.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this answer as a community wiki for the better visibility and to add some additional resources as the solution was posted in the comments by user @David Maze:

> If the pods are in different clusters, they can't directly communicate with each other (without using NodePort or LoadBalancer services, or otherwise making the destination service accessible from outside its own cluster).

---

With the most common setups the way to communicate `Pod1` from `Cluster1` with `Pod2` with `Cluster2` would be to use:

- `Service` of type `NodePort`
- `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`
- `Ingress` resource - specific to `HTTP`/`HTTPS` traffic

All of the above solutions will heavily depend on where your Kubernetes cluster is deployed.

For example:

With cloud solutions like `GKE`, `AKS`, `EKS` you can use service type of `LoadBalancer` or `Ingress` resource to direct the traffic to your pod.

With bare metal solution you would need to use additional tools like `MetalLB` to use service of type `LoadBalancer`

You could also look on this resources:

- *[Istio.io: Install: Multicluster: Gateways](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/gateways/)*
- *[Istio.io: Blog: Multi-cluster mesh automation](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/multi-cluster-mesh-automation/)*

---

As for an example assume that you have 2 Kubernetes clusters that can expose traffic with service of type `LoadBalancer`.

Apply on **first** cluster:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 3 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Check the `EXTERNAL-IP` associated with the service:

- `$ kubectl get service nginx-service`

```sh
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-service   LoadBalancer   10.92.10.48   A.B.C.D     80:30994/TCP   26s
```

Switch to **second** cluster and run:

- `$ kubectl run -it ubuntu --image=ubuntu -- /bin/bash`
- `$ apt update && apt install curl`
- `$ curl A.B.C.D`

You should be able to see:

```sh
<--- REDACTED ---> 
<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
<--- REDACTED --->
```

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Concepts: Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Medium.com: Kubernetes NodePort vs LoadBalancer vs Ingress, when I should use what](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-nodeport-vs-loadbalancer-vs-ingress-when-should-i-use-what-922f010849e0)* - could be somewhat specific to `GKE`